# When setting up IIS passthrough authentication, is there anything I need my network or server people to do?

Tags: iis, passthrough

I moved our website to an updates IIS on a new server. Is there anything I need ask our network people or server people to do?

I am have two issue that may be related.
When disabling Anonymous Authentication, all user get asked to log in. When enabling it SOME users get asked to log in. In both case windows authentication is enabled.

The other issue is when clicking a link to a file on a file server, it does nothing.

After much searching I am beginning to think the issue are related, like there needs to be a network or file service permission that needs to be set.

EDIT: I'm just trying to find out if I need to change anything in networks, have the server added to AD, or what, in order to access a file server.
I'm in a bad situation and it's a legit question. I'm not sure why I was down modded.

Comment: 1. Anonymous authentication takes highest priority, so when it is enabled all other authentication modes are ignored. 2. Login prompt is expected, when you disable anonymous authentication and leave Windows authentication on. Users do need to log in then. 3. It is Windows "authentication", not "authorization", so please learn the differences via search engines. Therefore, that's not an issue but the desired behavior after you changed the configuration. You need to provide more details on "when clicking a link to a file on a file server, it does nothing". IIS is not a file server.

Comment: I've tried everything I can find on google regarding setting up IIS.
I am asking if I need the network people or file server people to adjust any permission. 
The webserver uses networkservice identity for the application pool.
Do I need to request the webserver be put into a domain to access the file server? Do user need to be in the same domain or group as the webserver?
That sort of thing is what I am trying to figure out.

There is page served up by the web server that has a link to a pdf on a file server.
Clicking oin the ling to A fileserver does nothing.

Comment: If your organization has domain administrators, it is now the time to ask them for help, instead of asking yourself to learn everything from scratch. IIS servers usually should be enrolled to a domain, unless you are setting up DMZ.

Comment: I asked our network people for help and they told me they'll do what I ask, but won't tell me what I need.
THank you for your reply, I do appreciate it.